# Download and extract parts containing specific file from split 7z archive?

Tags: 7-zip, archiving, file-archiver

There's a file I want that's part of a very large, split 7z archive. Instead of downloading the entire 100gb archive, I'm wondering if it's possible to access the Compressed Metadata Block/End Header by downloading the last few parts of the archive, and use that to locate, download, and extract the specific parts my file is located in? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks.